# Angular 4 router.events don't seem to trigger RoutesRecognized event for the first time the user navigates

Tags: angular, events, router

This is a simple ts code that tests router triggered events

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RoutesRecognized } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
  })
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

 constructor(private router: Router) {
  this.router.events.subscribe((e)=>{console.log(e)})
 }

 ngOnInit() {}
}
```

The only event that is triggered is NavigationEnd. Where do i catch the rest of the events?

Answer (score 1):

misutkame, I hope this is not too late, I've encountered the same problem. I believe it is due to Router event being triggered before the component's life cycle began. Thus what you are asking cannot be directly addressed. 
There are several ways to work around it though.

1. Use a snapshot of the activated route during the child component's creation. This way you'll get router data that is required by your logic during the component's life cycle. You'll still need to set up a listener for later events.
2. Have the parent component listen to the router event, update a behaviorSubject and pass it to the child as input.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `RoutesRecognized`:

```
import { RoutesRecognized} from '@angular/router';


ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events
      .filter((e: any) => e instanceof RoutesRecognized)
      .pairwise()
      .subscribe((e: any) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }
```

Comment: what if i want to catch these events from the component i am routed at? This seems to be catched from the root app component. Is there an explanation for this? I mean, why these events are catched earlier, and not available later, after the component i want to route to is initiated?

Comment: trying to understand what is happening.

Comment: I already read that post, but this is not the case. The problem is that if i have a route config to .. lets say localhost:4200/user and bind it with userComponent, the only event that I get from the router is NavigationEnd. Why don't I have access from the user component constructor to the other events that the router is triggering?

Comment: As you see in the code example, i want to catch these events from the routed component, not the app-root component

Comment: well, did as instructed. for the RoutesRecognized event there is no match in the if statement. did you check it yourself? is it working on your setup? i am using angular 4

Comment: yess, it works for me too  :what about last edit :))))))

Comment: This is beyond my comprihantion. if i enable enable tracing on the route config, i can see all the triggered events by the router. the only event that i can see from my code is this: NavigationEnd. where are the other ones? That is what i am looking for...